# Confused about plotting origin in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

**Code**

```
self.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height
```

Here I am trying to set my views origin  to my view-height of the keyboard

**My output**

[image]

**My Doubt**

my view has to go below the keyboard according to math, what is happening?

Comment: The view coordinate start from top-left corner, so (0, 0) is top-left not bottom-left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate space that `UIView`s are in is not exactly the same as the cartesian coordinate plane you learned in math class, which might look something like this:

[image]

In UIKit, the positive y direction is downwards, and the negative y direction is upwards. This means that a view with a small y coordinate will be at the top of its superview. As you increase its y coordinate, it moves downwards. It looks something like this:

[image]

This line of code:

```
self.view.frame.origin.y=self.view.frame.origin.y-keyboardSize.height
```

decreases the y coordinate of `self.view`, hence moving it *up*. By how much? Well, the keyboard's height.

Comment: what about x axis?

Comment: @newjourney x axis is the same. As you increase the x coordinate, it moves to the right.

Answer (score 0):

View coordinate system increaes from top (0) to bottom (device height) , so this

```
self.view.frame.origin.y=self.view.frame.origin.y-keyboardSize.height
```

raises the view as it decrease it's y origin position

[image]